# There was an error with the AJAX request. XML/Json format is bad in whatsapp api

Tags: php, json, ajax, ffmpeg, whatsapp

I tried using the whatsapp API https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/wiki/Dependencies

I am using PHP 5.6.15 and I installed precompiled extension:
PHP Protobuf and curve25519 PHP but it does not appear in phpinfo(). I installed ffmpeg from here http://ukphpdeveloper.blogspot.com.eg/2012/08/how-to-install-ffmpeg-in-xampp.htmt but it didn't appear in phpinfo() as installed. I have my whatsapp password and username but when I try to execute

> /../whatsapp/Chat-API-master/examples/whatsapp.php

shows an error

> Error: There was an error with the AJAX request. XML/Json format is bad.